# WF4 How to focus an activity in the WorkflowDesigner without using the runtime-data

Tags: vb.net, workflow-foundation-4

I hosted a WorkflowDesigner in an existing WinFormsApplication and now I want to use the possibility to highlight an activity. 
But I mustn't use the runtime-engine of WF. I just use the WF to visualize an existing workflow in the WinFormsApp and this App also take care about the runtime issue. 
So how can I set the focus on an activity in the WorkflowDesigner without running the workflow in the Designer-class.

```
1 root.Properties("Nodes").Collection(i).Focus
2 Me.wd.DebugManagerView.CurrentLocation = CType(service.RetrieveAllViewState(root.Properties("Nodes").Collection(i)).Item("ShapeLocation"), SourceLocation)
```

First I thought I can just create a function that focus the avtive FlowNode but it did't work like this (line 1)...
Then I thought about telling the DebugManagerView what the Location of the active activity is. But I can not cast a ShapeLocation to a SourceLocation.
So how can I get the SourceLocation of the known active Activity.

I'm new in programming with the WorkflowFoundation and the .NET Framework so the whole possibilities are still a bit confusing for me.